# MySQL gett rows from last week with their day name

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble with a query. This is taken from a similar query where i count number of rows per month.

I want to count all rows for each day of the last week and display the day name and a count. If there are no rows for that day, display zero.

I know the UNIONS won't work but i don't know what to replace it with.

At the moment it get the last 7 days but the day name is NULL

```
SELECT  DAYNAME(STR_TO_DATE(Days.ID, '%a')) AS `day`, COUNT(`returns`.list_date) AS `total`
FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 as ID UNION SELECT 2 as ID UNION  SELECT 3 as ID UNION SELECT 4 as ID 
  UNION  
  SELECT 5 as ID UNION SELECT 6 as ID UNION SELECT 7 as ID
) as Days

    WHERE (list_date  >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
GROUP BY Days.id
```

**UPDATE:**

I have created a SQL fiddle showing the code output from @Gordon Linoff answer below which doesn't get the counted rows

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/969463/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method for doing what you want is a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL Days.n DAY)) AS `day`,
       COUNT(r.list_date) AS `total`
FROM (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2 as n UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 as n UNION ALL SELECT 4 as n UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 as n UNION ALL SELECT 6 as n UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 as n
     ) Days LEFT JOIN
     returns r
     ON r.list_date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL Days.n DAY))
GROUP BY Days.n
ORDER BY Days.n;
```

Some notes:

- Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, unless you have a good reason for incurring the overhead of removing duplicates.
- This assumes that `returns.list_date` is actually a date, because it uses `=` rather than `>=`.
- The use of `now()` and `>=` is a bit confusing, because `now()` has a time component, which you generally want to ignore.

Comment: Just tried this and I get zero for all days. I even just added a row for 3 days ago and it's not picking it up. Any ideas?

Comment: If I had to guess, your `list_date` has a time component.

Comment: Just read your note about list_date being a date and I used >= and it worked

Comment: How would I update the query to get all rows by a specific sender (column called Sender)